# Displaying Product Properties in a Static Block

Tags: cms, blocks, static-block

Short of creating my own widget or block class to do so, is there a way to display a product's name, sku, price, or other property in a static block or CMS page?

If there isn't a way to do this out of the box, is there a well excepted way to achieve this?

That is, I'd like to be able to do something like this in a block or page

```
{{block type="some/block" sku="PRODUCT_SKU" variable_to_display="name"}}
```

and have the product's name appear in the static-block/page.

Does this exist in Magento's core?  Somewhere in the community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not fully aware of a **core** means to go about this (I've not looked), but the following isn't particularly difficult to implement.

Just a few days ago, we needed the output from a helper - passed back into another helper, rendered via a CMS block.

This won't require `phtml` files to be created just for the sake of a single function - and will allow a fairly flexible use of `helper` or `model` methods to be executed.

Whilst probably not the clean core solution you want, the output should be what you are after.

#### Calling Helper Methods

There is no fault tolerance in this (ie. checking a method/class even exists etc.); but if you really need it, you could modify it to suit.

What I wanted was to fetch the return value of a helper that got the minimum price of a bundle product; then push that output through the currency helper to format it appropriately.

```
{{block type="sonassi.core/helper" helper="sonassi.core/catalog" function="getMinMaxPrice" arg1="5" arg2="" arg3="min" callback_helper="core" callback_function="currency" callback_arg1="function_response" callback_arg2="true" callback_arg3="false"}
```

Which was rendered using the following class.

```
<?php
/*
* @category    Module
* @package     Sonassi_Core
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Sonassi
*/
class Sonassi_Core_Block_Helper extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
  protected function _toHtml()
  {
    try {
      $args = $this->getData();
      $_helper = Mage::helper($args['helper']);
      $html = false;
      $argStr = implode("###", array_keys($args));
      if (preg_match_all('/arg[0-9]+/', $argStr, $matches)) {
        $data = array_intersect_key($args,array_flip($matches[0]));
        array_walk($data, array(Mage::helper('sonassi.core'),'stringToBoolean'));
        $html = call_user_func_array(array($_helper, $args['function']), $data);
      }
      if (isset($args['callback_helper'])) {
        $_callbackHelper = Mage::helper($args['callback_helper']);
        if (preg_match_all('/callback\_arg[0-9]+/', $argStr, $matches)) {
          $data = array_intersect_key($args,array_flip($matches[0]));
          $testCase = array_flip($data);
          if (isset($testCase['function_response'])) {
            $position = $testCase['function_response'];
            $data[$position] = $html;
          }
          array_walk($data, array(Mage::helper('sonassi.core'),'stringToBoolean'));
          $html = call_user_func_array(array($_callbackHelper, $args['callback_function']), $data);
        }
      }
      return $html;
    } catch(Exception $e) {}
    return;
  }
}
```

#### Calling Model Methods

So tweaking the above code ever-so-slightly *(I've stripped out the helper callback just to shorten the amount of code)*.

You could execute,

```
{{block type="sonassi.core/model" model="catalog/product" load_attribute="sku" load_value="product-sku" function="getName"}}
```

With the following supporting class,

```
<?php
/*
* @category    Module
* @package     Sonassi_Core
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Sonassi
*/
class Sonassi_Core_Block_Model extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
  protected function _toHtml()
  {
    try {
      $args = $this->getData();
      $_model = Mage::getModel($args['model'])
      if (isset($args['load_id']))
        $_model->load($args['load_id']);
      elseif (isset($args['load_attribute']) && isset($args['load_value']))
        $_model->loadByAttribute($args['load_attribute'], $args['load_value']);
      $html = false;
      $argStr = implode("###", array_keys($args));
      if (preg_match_all('/arg[0-9]+/', $argStr, $matches)) {
        $data = array_intersect_key($args,array_flip($matches[0]));
        array_walk($data, array(Mage::getModel('sonassi.core'),'stringToBoolean'));
        $html = call_user_func_array(array($_model, $args['function']), $data);
      }
      return $html;
    } catch(Exception $e) {}
    return;
  }
}
```

This class was kept fairly generic and loading a whole method for one method would be heavy - but you can just tailor it to your needs.

Obviously something like this would be more lightweight, but you can tweak your methods to suit your needs.

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

#### Common Method

The referenced helper method above, `stringToBoolean`, was just the following:

```
public function stringToBoolean(&$value, $key)
{
  if ($value == "true")
    $value = true;
  elseif ($value == "false")
    $value = false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for Yup, had something similar in mind — but I'd rather not roll my own if there's a solution out there that's already been stress tested under real world use.